# view not getting upadated in angular js when I pass dynamic ID's

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am passing dynamic id through ng-init method to method in controller and fetching response through ajax calls. I am trying to print the response its not getting printed. I using ng-repeat to repeat the list and calling ng-init for every element in list. But, the response is coming view not getting updated.

HTML code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 chalg-list" ng-repeat="element in elements">
 <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-9 pzero" ng-init="getActivity(element.id)">               
 <p><span>Activity Names</span> <span>{{names._element.id}}</span></p> 
 </div>
 </div>



Javascript code



$scope.getActivity(_id){
//getting response through ajax calls    
            $scope.names._id = data; //here every time dynamic id will come but the view not getting updated
        console.log($scope.activities._id)     
  }
```

Please, kindly help me I am running out of time

Comment: Not directly related, but nevertheless - you should not use ng-init for initialization pruposes, do it in a controller instead ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have the elements in your controller. Why do you need to call the `getActivity` from the view? Why not better do all this from the controller and have just the ng-repeat to display your data?

You will have something like this in your controller:

```
var arrElements = [1,2,3]; // your id's here
$scope.elements =[]; 
arrElements.forEach(function(item){
   // get your data here for every id $http .... 
   // push it into the emelents
   $scope.elements.push( .... );
});
```

In your view:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 chalg-list" ng-repeat="element in elements">
     <!-- show your data here -->
     {{element}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Angular's $digest cycle is not fired. How do you retrieve AJAX content, via `$http` service or by some other means? `$scope.$appyAsync()` would most probably help.

**Edit:** It's worth noting that if you have a chance to let Angular do it for you, you should probably use that. Angular's `$http` service, for example, triggers $digest cycle automatically for you.

Comment: I am using $http only

Comment: And you update scope values in $http's `success()` handler? Can you show all of the code? Have you double checked that the request is indeed successfully completed?